# SQL Query for rows having one value repeated and count null values

Tags: sql, count, group-by, null

I have this query below and it shows me emails that have been open and not open

This is done by a `left join` on `a_customerid = a_opens.oid`

Now the problem I'm having is grouping the email's finding out if the ID appears more than null 15 times . This query display zero addresses even when I look for a lower count.

```
SELECT a_customer.email
  FROM a_Customer LEFT OUTER JOIN a_Opens 
    ON a_Customer.ID = a_Opens.oID
 WHERE a_opens.oid is null
 GROUP BY a_customer.email
HAVING COUNT(a_Opens.oID) > 15;
```

Comment: It would help if you post the schema for the two tables.

Comment: `having count (*) > 15`

Comment: juergen d Worked thank you